# Timepoint translations location

Tags: support, localization, timestamps, time

There are timepoint strings, e.g.: "1 day ago", "in the next 4 days" etc. For instance, on the currently happening [moderator election on ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/5):

> [image: Moderator election timepoints]

I can't found these strings on traducir. Where are they actually located? How the community translation team can update these translation?

Comment: [I found the strings containing "ago" here in Traducir for Russian.](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=ago) I'm not sure about the strings for translating times in the future (e.g. "in [X] days" or "in [X] hours").